# How do I narrow down my results to 1 per user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following code, that retrieves contracts from users and returns them in ascending or descending order. This will display every contract for every user. How do I limit this query to 1 result for every user, as I'm only looking for the last or first contract?

```
first_contract =  Contract.objects.select_related('user').order_by('contract_start')

last_contract =  Contract.objects.select_related('user').order_by('-contract_start')
```

Model:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    contract_start = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    contract_end = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
```

Putting [:1] on the end is not what I'm looking for, this will only give me 1 result of 1 user.

Edit:

My View:

```
def get(self, request):
    users = User.objects.all().exclude(is_superuser=True)
    user_contracts = User.objects.annotate(first_contract=Min('contracts__contract_start'), last_contract=Max('contracts__contract_start'))
    return render(request, 'user/list_all.html', {
        'users': users,
        'user_contracts': user_contracts,
    })
```

My Template:

```
{% for user in users %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ user.employee.number }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.employee.location }}</td>
    <td>{{ contract_start }}</td>
    <td>{{ contract_end }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Where it says contract_start and contract_end is where the dates of the last contract should be displayed. I have more places where I need to use this, but this one is the easiest to show.

Comment: Have you tried to add .distinct(“user”)? first_contract =  Contract.objects.select_related('user').order_by('contract_start').distinct(“user”)

Comment: @Kristiyan Gospodinov This gives me the following error:

DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Comment: This will work on databases which supports Distinct like Postgres. In your case you can group the records and get the last/first one. You can do this with .annotate().

Comment: Could you give an example? I find the documentation on this hard to understand.

Comment: Doesn't give any errors (apart from typo near start), but it returns all contracts for each user still. I changed Max("id") to Max("user_id") which gave me 1 result for each user, but only of 2 users, while there's definetely more in my table.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only when is the first contract or the last one you can use this.

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='contracts')
    contract_start = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    contract_end = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
```

View

```
def get(self, request):
    user_contracts = User.objects.exclude(is_superuser=True).annotate(first_contract=Min('contracts__contract_start'), last_contract=Max('contracts__contract_start'))
    return render(request, 'user/list_all.html', {
        'user_contracts': user_contracts,
    })
```

In the template

```
{% for user in user_contracts %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ user.employee.number }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.employee.location }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.contract_start }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.contract_end }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: related='contracts' gives me: 
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'related'
Should it be related_name? Even then this doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: I’ve made some changes. Now it must work as expected.

Comment: Returns a queryset of all users, even those that don't exist in the contract database.

Comment: You can filter them. Simply add .filter(first_contract__isnull=False,last_contract__isnull=False) after the annotate.

Comment: That just narrows the users down though, but what I mean is that I now have a list of users that have a contract, there's no contract information about first or last contracts in the queryset.

Comment: Please share the code where you try to access first_contract or last_contract. P.S https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates